# Function results display

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a javascript i can use in html.

I want that when somebody clicks on the button Calculate, it runs the java script and then it should display the result. However, for some reason it dirrectly displays the result. Could somebody help me with this.

My file can be found here:

```js
function outputname() {
  var vl,vm,vc,il,ic,r, sum,x; 
  x=document.getElementById("Tool") ;
 
  vl=x.elements["VL"].value;
  vm=x.elements["VM"].value;
  vc=x.elements["VC"].value;
  il=x.elements["IL"].value;
  ic=x.elements["IC"].value;
  r=x.elements["R"].value; 

  

  sum=r;


 document.getElementById("Tool").innerHTML += " is not valid! <br>";
  document.getElementById("Tool").innerHTML += sum+"<br>";
  


}

outputname();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #119ed8;
}

label {
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: normal 16px ventura;
  color: white  
}

.button{
  width: 95px;
  font: normal 16px ventura;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.print{
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px; 
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <p><label for="Vectorlength">Vector length (bp):</label> 
    <input type="text" name="Vectorlength" value="" />
  </p>
  <p><label for="Vectormass">Vector mass (ng):</label> 
    <input type="text" name="Vectormass" value="" />
  </p>
  <p><label for="Vectorconcentration">Vector concentration (ng/µL):</label> 
    <input type="text" name="Vectorconcentration" value="" />
  </p>
  <p><label for="Insertlength">Insert length (bp):</label> 
    <input type="text" name="Insertlength" value="" />
  </p>
  <p><label for="Insertconcentration ">Insert concentration (ng/µL):</label> 
    <input type="text" name="Insertconcentration" value="" />
  </p>
  <p><label for="Ratio">Ratio Insert/Vector:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="Ratio" value="3" />
  </p>


</form>
<button onclick="outputname()">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by it directly displays the result

Comment: Your question isn’t very clear and you didn’t provide a [Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): there is no element with the ID `Tool`.

Comment: Its because you are calling the function as well in the last line of your script. Try calling the function on "onclick" of a button rather than calling it in script.

Answer (score 1):

Remove following code at last line

```
outputname();
```

In java script every line executed at a time of page loading. So in your case you are calling outputname() function at a time of loading it self.

put your button in form tag and modify your button click like this

```
<button onclick="outputname(); return false;">Submit</button>
```

this will prevent your form to submit after executing your function.

Comment: That is indeed the problem. A note about *"In java script every line executed at a time of page loading"* though: That's only true for the ones at global scope; ones in functions aren't executed until the functions are called (and are executed more than once if the function is called more than once). Again, though, you're right about what's wrong.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. That makes sense. However, when I remove that part of the function, the calculate button still doesn't work. What i'm doing wrong? (This is almost my first experience with java and html. Sorry for the 'stupid' questions)

Comment: try <button onclick="outputname(); return false;">Submit</button>